# Local JSON file Update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Hi trying to update the local JSON file with new input values.

Creating a posts app which is now working on local Json file.

I have a button and a text area, and a dynamic list.

once I add some input values in textarea and submit it should get appends to li and if I add another value then it should get append to another li.

What ever new values had added it should get append to the local json file.

Here is the code what I have tried.

HTML:

```
<ul class='Jsonlist'></ul>
<a id='postData' href='#'>Post</a>
<textarea id="tArea"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
var Json = {"three":["red","yellow","orange"]}
  var items = [];
$.each( Json, function( key, val ) {
    debugger;
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + Json.three + "</li>" );
  });
$('.Jsonlist').append(items);

$('#postData').click(function(){
    a=$('#tArea').val();
    $(".Jsonlist li").append(a);

});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2n5sP/)

Comment: You want that the input text to be added as a new li and appended into a local json file?

Comment: @JossefHarush: Yes Exactly..

Comment: K - working on the jsfiddle, update soon

Comment: @Viscocent: Hi Bro your answer is working perfectly.. Just I got my own fix: http://jsfiddle.net/2n5sP/3/ It would be a great pleasure if u help me out that the data should be there always even the browser is refreshed or closed...

Comment: @user1853128 what other technologies are you using asside from js?

Comment: @Viscocent: I am just developing a POC... Am completely a front end developer don't have knowledge on backend.. thats why trying to prepare on client side itself.. HTML5, CSS3, SASS, JS and Jquery

Comment: ok then we will need to use local storage. i will also need to update my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### JS fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JwCm9/

### What's inside?

variable to hold the items

```
var items;
```

creates `<ul>` for `items` and for each `item` a `<li>`

```
function make_list() {

    var list = $(".Jsonlist");
    list.empty();



    for (var i in items) {
        var value = items[i];
        var li = $('<li>');
        li.html(value);
        list.append(li);
    }


};
```

saving and reading from local json from/into `items`

```
function save_to_local_json() {
    var items_json = JSON.stringify(items);
    localStorage.setItem('items', items_json);
};


function read_from_local_json() {
    var items_json = localStorage.getItem('items');
    items = JSON.parse(items_json);

    // If the file is empty
    if (!items) {
        items = [];
    }
};
```

first time calling to these functions:

```
read_from_local_json();
make_list();
```

on click event

```
$('#postData').click(function () {
    var text = $('#tArea').val();
    items.push(text);
    make_list();
    save_to_local_json();
});
```

Comment: Exact output.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

updated my answer:

```
function update_json(json_data){
    localStorage.setItem('json',JSON.stringify(json_data));
}

function fetch_json(){
    var json_data_local = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('json'));
    return json_data_local;
}

function display_list(json_data){
    json_data.three.forEach(function(val,key) {
        $('.Jsonlist').append("<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
    });
}

console.log(localStorage.getItem('json'));
if(localStorage.getItem('json') == ""){
    var Json = {"three":["red","yellow","orange"]}
    update_json(Json);
}

var Json = fetch_json();

display_list(Json);

console.log(Json);
$('#postData').click(function(){
    a=$('#tArea').val();
    Json.three.push(a);
    update_json(Json); 
    $('.Jsonlist li').remove();
    display_list(fetch_json());
});
```

Comment: Would be nice if you could give some more explanation to what you did, etc.