# How to append current date and time into existing json file using jq

Tags: json, date, jq

I have below format of json file

```
{
  "username":"achu",
  "password":"test1234"
}
```

I just want to add timestamp into the above payload and send it as request for some service.

AS per I know the below command will help us to get current stamp on linux:

```
date +"%r"
```

but not sure how can I append this into the above payload as like below:

**Expected:**

```
{
  "username":"achu",
  "password":"test1234",
  "date":"1:20:30 AM PST"
}
```

> jq --version
>
> 1.5v

Is it possible to get it like this?

Comment: alternatively, you could achieve the same using a unix _walk-path_ tool `jtc`, assuming your input is in `file.json`: **`<file.json jtc -ei echo '{ \"date\": \"$(date +"%r %Z")\" }' \;`** (PS. I'm a developer of the `jtc` unix tool for JOSN processing).
`

Comment: try this solution :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557987/local-json-file-update/23558704

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JQ has builtin functions for playing with dates, such as:

```
. + {date: (now | strflocaltime("%r"))}
```

Comment: And if you want an ISO8601 date, jq has this: `(now | todateiso8601)` (among [other date things](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Dates).)

Answer (score 5):

One of many possibilities:

```
$ jq --arg date $(date +"%r") '. + {date: $date}'
```

p.s. The jq program could be written as:

```
. + {$date}
```

p.p.s. Rather than continually asking whether something is possible using jq, you might find it a better investment of your time to become more familiar with jq. A good reference is the official manual: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Comment: useful comment though :)

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk and gawk-json extension:

```
$ gawk '
@load "json"
{
   lines=lines $0                      # pack multiline json to a single record
   if(json_fromJSON(lines,data)==1) {  # convert json to an array
       data["date"]=strftime("%r %Z")  # get the date to the array
       print json_toJSON(data,1)       # output json
   }
}' file.json
```

Output in my tz:

```
{"username":"achu","password":"test1234","date":"07:46:57 AM EEST"}
```